# Настройка Python IDLE на macOS

Tags: python, настройка, idle

Возможно, мой вопрос покажется глупым для опытных:) Я начал использовать IDLE Python на ноутбуке с операционной системой macOS. Используя данную программу в Windows, я привык, что можно изменить цвет, размер текста и прочие внешние особенности среды через Options / Configure IDLE. Но в приложении на Mac такой клавиши нет. Подскажите, в чем я не прав?

Answer (score 0):

Когда находитесь в программе, наведите курсор мыши на верхний край экрана, должна будет выехать панель инструментов, где Вы сможете все настроить.